# Get element which have a specific data-* set

Tags: javascript, jquery, dataset, src

Say, I've a `<script data-src = "script.js">` somewhere in my DOM without any `id` or other identifiable attribute set. How could I select that element so that I can reset that element with correct src.

Like:

```
var el = //code

el.src = el.dataset.src;
```

Maybe I could loop all script tag and all, but is there a way to get specific element by just this info?

EDIT:

With pure javascript.

Comment: use attribute selector

Answer (score 1):

you can use query selector as following :

```
element = document.querySelectorAll("script[data-src]")[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with JavaScript's `querySelectorAll()`

```js
// Get the first script tag with the data attribute "data-src"
var theScript = document.querySelectorAll("script[data-src]")[0];

// write the data-src to the document
document.write(theScript.getAttribute('data-src'));
```

```html
<script data-src="testing.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(document).find('[data-src]')` to get the object. Note, if you have more objects with `data-src` then you have to loop through them.

```js
$(document).find('script[data-src]').attr("data-src", "News link")

console.log($(document).find('script[data-src]').data("src"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script data-src="script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

with pure Js.

```js
var el=document.querySelector('script[data-src]');

console.log(el.dataset.src);

el.dataset.src='correct-src.js';

console.log(el.dataset.src);
```

```html
<script data-src = "script.js">
</script>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery:**

```
$("script[data-src='script.js']")
```

For more details https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

**Javacript:**

```
document.querySelector('[data-src="script.js"]')
```

Form more details [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)